# Deploy docker images to heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, docker-registry, heroku-cli

[image]

[image]

I try to push container to Heroku by this command:

```
sudo heroku container:push web --app <my-heroku-app>
```

But I got this error "no basic auth credentials".

How to solve this??????

There are all of step from login to push docker images to heroku

1. first pattern

1.1
[image]

1.2
[image]

1.3
[image]

1.4
[image]

1.5
[image]

2. second Pattern

2.1
[image]

2.2.
[image]

2.3.
[image]

**Whole pattern got same problem 'no basic auth credentials'**

Answer (score 32):

Login in the Docker Registry before pushing

```
heroku container:login
```

Comment: I login and use command for push container already. But I got same problem same as before.

Comment: You could try to push with docker command `docker push registry.heroku.com/app/web` (btw you need both heroku login and heroku:container login)

Comment: it have same problem :(

Comment: Post all your steps (from login to push) and output, there must be something that doesn't go as expected

Comment: I added  my step.

Comment: Looks all fine to me :-( I would try push with docker command docker `docker push registry.heroku.com/app/web`, not sure if it makes a difference. You can also try to logout/login again, I really dont know why your steps fail, sorry

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to login into the registry, the first one is:

`heroku container:login`

but what worked for me was the following way:

`docker login --username=<your username> --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com`

[See the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry)